# Which one can use first, which or where in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Can we say following sentence:

> Let (T, F) be a locally constant function **which** defined on Example 1, where
>   T:X---->R.

or we have to say

> Let (T,F) be a locally constant function **where** T:X---->R, which defined on
>   Example 1.

Also, which is correct, "on Example" or "in Example"?

Comment: *...which **is** defined **by / in / with** Example 1*. Several prepositions are "acceptable" here, but ***on*** isn't one of them.

Comment: Agreed with FumbleFingers. "Where" also isn't appropriate unless you change the structure to something like "where it was defined in Example 1".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. what about sentences?which one is correct?

Comment: @JRodge01 :Thanks. what about sentences?which one is correct?

Comment: @RR: I don't understand the (algebraic?) *meaning* of your example. So I can't tell whether what's defined in Example 1 is "a locally constant function" *(**T**)* OR the (equation?) ***T:X---->R***. By default, ***which*** refers back to the nearest immediately-preceding noun (or noun phrase), so it makes a difference whether you put the ***which*** clause immediately after "a locally constant function" or after "T:X---->R". This depends on ***what you mean***, not "correct grammar" as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : "which" refers to (T, F) not T:X---->R.

Comment: Couldn't you have come up with an example that doesn't feature inscrutable algebraic expressions? This site is concerned with ***English***, not mathematical notation.

Comment: I suggest you read papers by other mathematicians, and copy their style.

Answer (score -1):

Both mean the same, but grammatically both are wrong. The correct will be:

> Let T be a locally constant function **which is** defined **in** Example 1,
>   where T:X---->R.

OR

> Let T be a locally constant function where T:X---->R, **which is** defined **in**
>   Example 1.

I'd personally prefer "***as*** defined in Example 1." instead of using "**which**".

Also, "**in, by or with**" can be used, but never **on**

Comment: I disagree that both mean the same. Even though I don't understand the sentence, I know enough to say that ***which*** either refers to "a locally constant function" OR to "T:X---->R", depending on where it's placed. And since we're told that the locally constant function is **T**, I don't see how that can be exactly the same thing as **T:X---->R**. I suppose it's at least *possible* that in your second version, ***which*** refers back to just **R** - but again, **R** can't be the same as **T**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers its a mathematical equation. T is defined as T:X---->R in an example. Now being defined in an example can be mentioned before or after. It doesn't make a difference by meaning

Comment: You'll have to enlighten me. I have an A-Level in maths and a degree in English, but I don't know what **T:X---->R** means, and I've no idea what syntactic category to assign to that "text".

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you don't know what it means, you can't claim they don't mean the same thing. Syntactically, forget about the meaning. (1) *which X, where Y* and (2) *where Y, which X*. This is roughly the equivalent of (1) *if X, then Y* and (2) *Y, if X*. Inasmuch as the meaning *is* unknown, I think it's likely that the syntax makes the two constructions equivalent. Therefore, I essentially agree with this answer. So, +1 from me.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment either! :) But I ***do*** understand that the default referent of an embedded ***which-*** clause in English is the nearest preceding noun phrase. From which it follows that the two sequences above have different defaults, which only (domain-specific) knowledge of the subject can override. Switching to non-domain-specific terms in a similar structure, compare *Let my party be at a local pub, **which is my favourite,** where they serve scampi* and *Let it be a local pub where they serve scampi, **which is my favourite***. Not the same.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your example makes use of different specific syntactical constructions. You change the noun to which *which* applies. It's not the same type of thing.

Comment: But that's my very point! I changed the (default) noun to which ***which*** applies by moving the clause itself! With no domain-specific knowledge, you ***must*** apply the same "default referent" principles regardless of whether it's ***which is defined in Example*** or ***which is my favourite***. In my examples, my favourite is EITHER ***that pub***, OR ***scampi***, and in Bella's examples what's defined in Example is EITHER ***a locally constant function*** OR ***T:X---->R*** (or feasibly just ***R*** is defined there, but I think maybe even that involves "domain-specific knowledge").

Comment: @FumbleFingers What you did was move *which* without also moving the noun it was attached to. That's not what the example in the question is doing. Both *which* and *where* are being moved along with their attached nouns. You break the two up; the example in the question does not.

Comment: The second example in the ***question*** isn't even grammatically valid. I'm talking about Bella's examples in ***this answer***, where the *only* difference is that the clause ***which is defined in Example 1*** has been moved from an intermediate position to the end of the utterance. As a result of which *syntactically*, the default noun that ***which*** refers back to must perforce change. Whatever - I don't think this back-and-forth is getting anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Neither of your examples are correct, and I don't believe you're mathematically formatting your functions correctly either.

> Let (T, F) be a locally constant function which defined on Example 1, where T:X---->R.

should likely be

> Let f(T, F) be a locally constant function where T:X->R.

There were 3 changes:

1. f() is how you normally denote a function.
2. Unless it is imperative that you call back to example 1, I wouldn't.  Add it as a foot note or as a second sentence if needed, or as "as defined in example 1" if you really want it in-line.
3. I'm unfamiliar with what you're conveying with T:X---->R, but assuming that T is going to cover a range of values from X to R.  Context may be helpful, but for word processing sake, you should shorten it to T:X->R.

Your word processor's math formula editor may be better so you can input the correct visual without having to transcribe it to words and circumvent the problem altogether.